# How to design a firestore data model for categories?

Tags: node.js, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, data-modeling

I wan to create a collection of categories where all categories can have as many children as they want.

Like if the user wants to add a additional category to a child, they can. How to design that? What would be the queries to add a category to the last child?

Comment: Is there a *multiple to multiple* relationship between categories and children?

Comment: nope there is not... the problem is that one subcategory can have a lot of children, like 5, but like other subcategory can only have like one child. So how should  model the database and what would queries look like

Answer (score 0):

Firestore is NoSQL database which by it's concept does not contain any designed schema so you do not need to design anything. It's just working as you described your needs - every document can contain different structure.

I suggest to reed [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model) about data model.

Looking at your description, you could be as well interested in Realtime Database also available in Firebase (but not in Google Cloud Console). It's as well NoSQL database, but is practically just large, easy to manage json tree. There is nice [article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore) about choosing database in Firebase documentation (but you can find lot of articles on the web as well).